# Child objects not binding to model in wcf web api

Tags: wcf-web-api

Him

I'm using the WCF Web API for creating a restful services. I've a method with following signature

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="AddJob")]
public string AddJob(Job job)
{
    //...
}
```

The Job object has a child object RecurDay. the posted values from the form are not binding to the RecurDay properties, in fact the RecurDay object itself is not getting created.

NOTE: The form fields are named same as the class properties. Ex. Id, JobName, RecurDay.Id, RecurDay.Day etc. The Id, JobName are mapped correctly but the Address.Id and RecurDay.Day are not getting mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to create a JSON object from your form data on the client and send this to your API - otherwise it won't get de-serialized.